# ldd equivalent in AIX?

Tags: unix, aix

I'm used to do a ldd -d libxxx.so in Linux but it doesn't work in this AIX machine, I looked and I found some places to download the ldd program, but I actually want to know if there is a default application to see the libraries dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html), the command you want is "dump -H".

Comment: Apparently `dump -H` is not reporting the full path to dependent modules. It is only showing the base filenames along with the library search paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [genld](http://www.regatta.cs.msu.su/doc/usr/share/man/info/ru_RU/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds2/genld.htm) to see what is loaded by the process or use dump-h as said Geoff Fritz.

Here's one [Ldd source code](http://www1.mager.org/aix/ldd.c) for aix.

hope this helps.